# How can I solve a captcha using Matlab?

Tags: matlab, download

Is it possible to download the three files on

http://www.nasdaq.com/screening/company-list.aspx

using urlread in Matlab (or some other way)? Downloading by hand requires solving a captcha, and I'm wondering if there's a way to get around that or make matlab prompt the user to solve the captcha.

Comment: The point of a captcha is to prevent a bot from downloading, so yeah, do it by hand.

Comment: The question title should be replaced to **"How can I solve a captcha using Matlab?"**

Comment: It can be done without captcha... but only because it's specific to the author's specified site. See my answer.

Comment: I'm voting to close, you are not asking how to solve captchas in MATLAB (OCR or as a computer vision task), just how to bypass it in this particular case..

Comment: @Amro, you should've seen the edits on the question. natan had suggested the change from the original title "Downloading Files using Matlab urlread" to current "How can I solve a captcha using Matlab?" Perhaps it should be rolled back to the original title.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Comments from others aside, here's the code that does what you're looking for, specific to your site... at least for as long as the links work:

```
str_nasdaq = urlread('http://www.nasdaq.com/screening/companies-by-name.aspx?letter=0&exchange=nasdaq&render=download');
str_nyse = urlread('http://www.nasdaq.com/screening/companies-by-name.aspx?letter=0&exchange=nyse&render=download');
str_amex = urlread('http://www.nasdaq.com/screening/companies-by-name.aspx?letter=0&exchange=amex&render=download');
```

It bypasses the JS captcha verification function in lines 671, 677, 682 in the current page that does something like:

```
javascript:confirmDownload('http://www.nasdaq.com/screening/companies-by-name.aspx?letter=0&exchange=nasdaq&render=download');
```

Comment: I have NoScript addon in Firefox (Javascript is only enabled for white-listed websites), and it appears to bypass the whole captcha in Javascript in this case